# paperclip image rotation not working with s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, imagemagick, paperclip

Thanks for attention,

I am trying to rotate image uploaded on s3 already. Here is what I implemented in app/models/pic.rb

```
def rotate!(degrees)
  self.rotation += degrees.to_i
  image.reprocess!
  image.save
  save!
end
```

Problem: when I save the image after rotation it saves in the default path instead of the original s3 image path. ie. it saves on s3 but in the wrong folder.

Here is paperclip config

```
def set_default_attachment_options
  Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.merge!(
    # Stripping EXIF data unless WW model gallery.
    # Ensuring RGB at 72dpi. Oversampling for smoother resizing. Applying unsharp mask.
    :convert_options => {
      :all       => lambda { |i| '-strip' unless i.respond_to?(:ww_model?) && i.ww_model? },
      :max       => '-colorspace RGB -density 72 -quality 85 -resize 200% -resize 50% -unsharp 1x1+.5+.1',
      :page      => '-colorspace RGB -density 72 -quality 85 -resize 200% -resize 50% -unsharp 1x1+.5+.1',
      :croppable => '-colorspace RGB -density 72 -quality 85',
      :thumb     => '-colorspace RGB -density 72 -quality 85',
    },
    :default_url     => '/assets/pending/:class/:attachment/:style.png',
    :hash_secret     => hash_secret,
    :path            => s3? ? attachment_url_format : attachment_path_format,
    :s3_credentials  => s3_credentials_yaml_path, # DISCUSS: do we need that or does aws-sdk give us that for free?
    :s3_headers      => { 'Cache-Control' => 'public', 'Expires' => 1.year.from_now.httpdate },
    :s3_host_alias   => cdn_host,
    :s3_protocol     => "https", # this makes http:// and https:// dynamic.
    :storage         => s3? ? :s3 : :filesystem,
    :url             => s3? ? ':s3_alias_url' : attachment_url_format,
    :use_timestamp   => false,
    :whiny           => !Rails.env.production?
  )
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution, mistakenly I forgot to set URL